# Find a simple expression for the exponential generating function $\bar{C}(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_n\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $c_n$ be the number of ways to choose a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ and then color each fixed point of $\pi$ either red or blue. Find a simple expression for the exponential generating function $\bar{C}(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_n\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

I'm thinking about using the composition of exponential generating function. Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to choose a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ and let $b_n$ be the number of ways to color each fixed point of $\pi$. However, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k} = 3^n $